# Polynomial code

Tags: c++, function, friend, istream

I'm working on an assignment for my C++ class and have run into a little problem when running the program. I get an error stating `Unhandled exception at 0x000944C8 in Pog11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.` while debugging. The goal is to read in the `int` degree of a polynomial, as well as the `double` coefficients.
here is the .h file that I was supplied:

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include<iostream>
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

class Polynomial
{
    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& left , const Polynomial&  right);
    friend istream& operator>>( istream& left , Polynomial& right );

public:
  Polynomial();
  Polynomial( int degree, const double* coefficients );
  Polynomial( const Polynomial& );
  ~Polynomial();

  const Polynomial& operator=( const Polynomial& deg);
  bool operator==( const Polynomial& deg ) const;
  void setDegree(int d);
  int getDegree() const;

private:
   int degree;
   double* coefficients;          
};
#endif
```

And here is the segment of code that is causing the error:

```
istream&  operator>>(istream& left, Polynomial& right)
{
    int tmp;
    left >> tmp;
    right.setDegree(tmp);
    int i = 0;
    while (i<=right.getDegree())
    {
        double co;
        left >> co;
        right.coefficients[i] = co;
        i++;
    }
    return left;
}
```

Specifically the `right.coefficients[i]=co;` line is what causes the program to crash.

Here are the constructors for the class:

```
#include "Polynomial.h"
Polynomial::Polynomial() :degree(0), coefficients(0)
{
degree = 0;
coefficients = new double[degree];

}
Polynomial::Polynomial(int deg, const double* coefficients)
{
if (deg < 0)
{
    degree = 0;
}
else
{
    degree = deg;
}
coefficients = new double [degree];
}
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& deg)
{
if (deg.getDegree() <= 0)
{
    setDegree(0);
}
else
{
    setDegree(deg.getDegree());
    for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++)
    {
        coefficients[i] = deg.coefficients[i];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How is `coefficients` initialized? The problem is in code that isn't included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There's code missing - e.g. the implementation of the constructor of the `Polynomial` object.

I'm pretty sure that your error is that you have not allocated (enough) memory for the `coefficients` data member. There must be a

```
coefficients = new double[number_of_coeffs]
```

somewhere in your code.

**EDIT**

There's a number of points where you need to do this: where the degree of the polynomial is (re)set. Because then you know the degree of the polynomial:

Here you must copy the elements passed:

```
Polynomial( int degree, const double* coefficients ):
    coefficients( new double[degree] ), degree( degree )
{
    ::memcpy(this->coefficients, coefficients, degree * sizeof(double));
}
```

and in this one, the degree of the polynomial changes - so your coefficients array must be modified accordingly.

```
Polynomial::setDegree( int degree ) {
     // first delete the old coefficients
     delete [] coeffs;
     // and make a new array
     this->degree = degree;
     this->coefficients = new double[ this->degree ];
     // initialize the coefficients
     ..
 }
```

Similar actions have to be done in the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

Finally: you might be better off using `std::vector<double>` which basically does all the memory management for you. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Where would you recommend putting this new line? I'm still fairly new at coding and am still trying to get everything figured out. Thanks